# Is there any documentation on what API Gateway supports in greedy path variables?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

API Gateway Greedy path variables do not seem to support dashes. For example, from a serverless config for a lambda backed api:

```
router:
  handler: app/lambdas.router
  events:
  - http:
      method: get
      path: app/{action+}
```

Requests to urls like `/app/foo_bar` are mapped correctly, but urls like `/app/foo-bar` fail with:

```
{
  message: "Internal server error"
}
```

There is no error in the lambda in cloudwatch, so I assume this is some sort of routing error. Is there any documentation on what api gateway actually supports for greedy path variables (or how to get it to support dashes without enumerating them all out explicitly)?

Comment: Are you sure the internal server error is not caused by your lambda not properly handling the other path?

Comment: @luk2302 - that was the first thing I verified. The lambda is not invoked only if the greedy parameter contains a `-`. The next step will be enabling cloudwatch logging for API Gateway - I was hoping that  there was some documentation I had missed regarding what is permitted in a greedy parameter. (Like, what is the deal with the +, are there any other parameters that are supported, is it possible to have multiple parameters, etc...)